# How can I deal with file association in different application(not in Nautilus)?

Tags: 11.04, file-association

Maybe i don't understand the system.
Upgraded to (reinstalled) Ubuntu 11.04.

Is there any way the applications can use something that i set in nautilus, or it's just a wrong idea about the usage?

In nautilus the file association works great, easy, handy and so on...

My first problem was when installed chromium. Downloaded a file, a popup ask for assocation, set nautilus. And it only opens folder, for any file show an error:  it is not a direcrory. Ok, so i thought Google chrome changed, because previously .pdf open acrobat,.torrent open vuze and so on. But now i have to open nautilus on download folder with it, than select and open the preferable application by manually and can't use any automatism i used to.

Then in gnome commander , it not followed the default association i set in nautilus. Ok maybe it is commander fault. use it's own.

Then in calibre, the "read" use again this default "can't open its not a directory" error

So it's seems to me the applications not using well this file associations or i really don't understand the aim of file associations system (mime,.desktop files,...)

If there is no solution i think i have to search some program (if any exist's) which can identify and launch application and set as default instead nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the line in `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

`inode/directory=rhythmbox.desktop;vlc.desktop;smplayer.desktop;`

and insert

`inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;`

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the `.desktop` file from that application and add the mime type

e.g. (the examples below are from an application that i had to fix myself)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Guitar Pro 6
Comment=Tablature Edition Software
Exec=GuitarPro6 %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=GuitarPro6.png
Categories=Application;AudioVideo;
MimeType=audio/x-gtp;
```

The last line from the example shows the association.

If you want to create a new mimetype you should do this:
Create a new file at `/usr/share/mime/packages/`

e.g. `GuitarPro6.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="audio/x-gtp">
        <comment>Guitar Pro tab</comment>
            <glob pattern="*.gpx"/>
            <glob pattern="*.gp3"/>
            <glob pattern="*.gp4"/>
            <glob pattern="*.gp5"/>
        </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

After you create the file just run `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime/`

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment out (by adding "#" in front of the line)

> x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop

from this file:

> .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

Credits to [Stop folders opening with different application than the file manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73979/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-open-folders-with-nautilus-by-default)
and [UbuntuForums: Can't open files directly from Chrome - opens Nautilus](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863044) for the link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I found the solution on [another forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1757867).

To make short:

> uninstall `exo-utils` (and all dependencies).

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I've created the `vue.xml` and `vue.desktop` file, updated the mime type database with:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime/
```

but received the error

> **`Unknown media type in type 'office/vue'`**

Then I changed the `<mime-type type="office/vue">` and `MimeType=office/vue` to `<mime-type type="application/vue">` and `MimeType=application/vue`, and that worked.

Correct mime type file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">  
    <mime-type type="application/vue">  
        <comment>Vue file</comment>  
            <glob pattern="*.vue"/>  
            <glob pattern="*.vpk"/>  
        </mime-type>  
</mime-info>
```

And my *.desktop file was:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Encoding=UTF-8  
Name=VUE  
Categories=Office  
Exec=java -jar /usr/share/VUE/VUE.jar  
Icon=/usr/share/VUE/vue.gif  
StartupNotify=false  
Terminal=false  
Type=Application  
Comment=Visual Understanding Environment Application  
StartupWMClass=tufts-vue-VUE  
MimeType=application/vue
```