# Problem running .jar as excetutable-- i'm confused

Tags: java

I'm new here and relatively new to linux. Running Ubuntu 12.04 on a dell xps m140. I am trying to run a .jar 'applet (is that the correct word?). It is a server to use my android as a wireless mouse over wifi. I tried executing it with openjava 6 and 7, and keep getting this problem; however it worked fine the first time I ran it...

I right click on the file "AioServer3.4.2.jar" and select to open with the java 6/7 runtime. The app appears to open, I see the little icon appear in the status bar/thing at the top with the time, log in and power options, volume ect (again, idk the word for it). I right click the icon and click 'show/hide application' and where as I used to see the app and use the program, all that appears is this gray and white box in the top left corner of my screen just to right of the launcher. I tried posting a screenshot but I am not able to yet. Can anyone help? Why am I not seeing the application?

Comment: Is the jar exported as runnable? I do not know android but I know java. If it's not exported as runnable, then you can use java -classmate option to include jar.

Answer (score 0):

What about [(opening a terminal)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it) and running:

```
java -jar /path/to/externalJarFile.jar
```

If you want to be able to double click: [Check Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click)

And to make the jar file executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/the.jar
```

Comment: Ran from terminal and it appeared to work, but then the same thing happened. It is already marked as executable in the properties.