# Running linux downloads - total noob

Tags: software-installation, downloads, executable

I am a COMPLETELY new user to linux and have been using most of my programs through wine. Take for example this program : http://www.atlauncher.com/download/jar/ which, when unpacked has no executable files. I'm not sure if I am looking for the wrong type of file but I would really appreciate some help on how to get downloads like this with no obvious runnable files up and running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click

Comment: I really have no clue what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't extract `.jar` files, because they are [Java Archives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) and should therefore be executed using Java (or in case of a library included in your project). Ubuntu opens `.jar` using the Archive Manager by default because it is actually a ZIP file.

So you should install Java first. If you haven't already, you can execute the following commands to install OpenJDK (an open source version of Java):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Now you can open the `.jar` file using `java -jar file.jar` in the terminal or by double clicking it in your file manager.

Comment: Thanks so much and now I have the option to open with java but when I do it returns the message :The file '/home/matthew/Desktop/ATLauncher.jar' is not marked as executable. ------ Oops a similar question quickly helped me solve this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Right click the file, click `Properties`, click `Permissions`, check `Allow executing file as program`. You can also use `chmod +x file.jar` in a terminal which will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

That particular file you have downloaded is a Java file; by default, Linux, will not grant executable rights to files - you need to grant that privilege.

### Quick answer

A) You need Java (unless you have that):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

B) You'll need to correct the permissions:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
chmod +x <file>.jar
```

C) To run: `java -jar <file>`