# How to open jar file with doubleclick after upgarade to 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, java, openjdk

After upgrading to 14.04. I ran into problems with opening .jar files. Double clicking on `Client.jar` doesn't open it. I tried  right clicking and selecting both , OpenJDK Java 7 runtime and OpenJDK Java 6 runtime with no success.

Program runs fine from Eclipse and I can run it from terminal using  `java -jar Client.jar`, but it's somewhat inconvenient.

How can I make it run by double-clicking the .jar file ?

P.S.

Double clicking on .jar worked fine on 12.04.

Comment: What about something from here?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click

Comment: Unfortunately none of those solutions worked. Launching .jar file using oracle's java has the same result as using openJDK, nothing happens. I tried creating .desktop file containing `Exec=java -jar Client.jar` (I also tried absolute address) but that didn't work either. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Ok, I found a workaround. Launching it from bash script file works, but IMHO that's not a normal solution. I will appreciate any ideas on how to normally launch .jar files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenJDK not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/640211/openjdk-not-working)