# chmod command problem Xubuntu

Tags: command-line, jar

Hello I'm trying to make a jar executable using chmod a+x jarname.jar, no errors. But when I try to execute it it's not executable. .. help plz, I'm on Xubuntu, trying to execute the jausing DOUBLE MOUSE CLICK

When e double click it it shows me this:

[image: terminal + block window]

Comment: Please provide the output error.

Comment: There is no error

Comment: Whenever you ask a question, we need to see _the exact_ command you run. How did you try to execute the `jar` file?

Comment: I'm not trying to execute it using The terminal, I use chmod command to set the jar file double click executable

Comment: no dude, in xubuntu to run a jar file with double click the jar has to be executable or you'll get a error window telling you that the file is blocked "is not marked as Executable"...

Comment: Ah. This is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/11840/158442 then.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a jar file you need to use the `java` command. There's lots of information on how to do this available via Google [run a jar in linux](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=run+a+jar&oq=run+a+jar&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3272j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=run+a+jar+in+linux). But the simplest command is:
`java -jar jarname.jar`

If you want to run it by double clicking [How run a .jar file with a double-click?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click) should help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Just Moved the .jar file on the desktop and changed the mod again

`chmode a+x sql_fat.jar`