# How to run a downloaded program for use with Betfair

Tags: command-line

I have downloaded a program (called MT3) which is for submitting bets on Betfair, the sellers say it is approved by Betfair and compliant with their latest requirements, and will work under the Linux os..   I am using Ubuntu 12.04

After downloading and extracting I can see that a folder called mt3 has been created and it contains another folder called files, the only item in this folder is licence.rtf the licence agreement.   At the same level in the mt3 folder are 5 `.jar` files (betting, jsonshared, json-simple-1.1.1. mt3 and navigation) the 4 other files at the same level are icon.icns icon.ico icon.png and manifest.txt

The vendors say that after downloading, and unzipping the files all you do is click on the file called mt3.jar...  when I do that it simply takes me to other folders (com and META-INF) and all their contents.  I cannot see how to make the program run, can you give me any guidance please.  Java (7) has been installed from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: Keep in mind that  the standard OpenJDK does not have Java Webstart, which is  typically used to launch jar files on double-click.  (Probably not technically accurate.)  That said, you don't have to install Oracle Java. as it will most likely run from OpenJDK too.  Try running something like `java -jar mt3.jar`.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of  http://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click

Answer (score 0):

The following instructions were tested in Xubuntu 14.04 running in VirtualBox, because I don't like installing a betting program in a host OS, and even though mt3 does not run as root neither should you.

1. Make a new folder on your desktop called mt3.
2. Download the .zip (mt3.zip) from www.chromaweb.com to the mt3 folder.
3. Unzip it.
4. Open the terminal and navigate using `cd` to the mt3 folder you've unzipped it to. There should be a file in it called mt3.jar.
5. Run the mt3.jar file with this command:

   ```
   java -jar mt3.jar
   ```
6. An mt3 login window will open.

   [image]